# how to hide the google chart axis for bar charts

Tags: google-visualization

For a google bar chart i want to hide the axis or change their color to white.

```
chart.googleapis.com/chart?chd=t%3A10%2C8%2C6%2C7%2C8&cht=bhs&chs=80x67&chco=000000|000000|000000|000000|000000&chf=&chxt=&chxr=&chxp=&chbh=11%2C1&chxs=0%2CFFFFFF%2C13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Make It Perfect - try to use the below url:

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chd=t%3A10%2C8%2C6%2C7%2C8&cht=bhs&chs=80x67&chco=000000|000000|000000|000000|000000&chf=&chxr=&chxp=&chbh=11%2C1&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,000000,0,0,_,000000|1,000000,0,0,_,000000
```